# Some clarification of iTunes in-app purchase items

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, itunes

I am trying to test the in-app purchasing on iOS. I work more with Android, so I am a bit confused as the process is slightly different than in Android.

I created a few in-app purchase items, IAPs, as you can see on the image

[image]

What should I do now? The instructions say that I have to submit the app along with the first in-app. But how can I submit the app when it has not been finished yet? Do I submit the current build regardless of the fact the app may crash or some other features have not been started?

Also, is the screenshot really mandatory?

Thanks anyone for help.

Comment: Why do you want to submit the in-app items before your app is ready?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Screenshots are indeed mandatory. Strange, but required non the less.

As far as I can remember, when you come to submitting the app there should be a section that allows you to specify which In App Purchases you want to submit as well.

I do recall that I found this highly confusing as it does seem that you are in a catch 22 situation where you can't submit the App without the IAP's and vice versa.

You need to provide all the required fields for the In App Purchases so that the status is "Prepared for submission" or "Awaiting review" (I can't remember which status comes first) before you can then select them on the stage before you submit your binary for review.

Comment: Can I send partially finished app? Or I have to implement iaps at the "very, very end"?

Comment: You should submit the app in it's entirety. There wouldn't be much point submitting a partially finished app as it would most likely be rejected by Apple. You can test IAP's on a device before submission but not in the simulator.

Comment: So I can test IAPs without submitting them? That is great. Are those you see valid for testing? I mean, how do I know that they are valid for testing - is there any visual sign that they are valid?

Comment: As long as they have been set up with all the required parameters, you should be able to test them in your app when it's running on a device. What you have so far should be sufficient.